# Help getting query right

Tags: query

I am writing two queries, and I am having problems getting this right.
I have the following set up:

Opportunity

**Policy__c**
Source_Opportunity__c (Lookup to Opportunity)

**Policy_Coverage__c**

Policy__c(Lookup to Policy__c)

**Section_Address_Link__c** (Junction Object)

Policy_Coverage__c (Lookup to Policy_Coverage__c)

Section_Address__c (Lookup to Section_Address__c)

**Section_Address__c**

I need to query from Section Address all the way up to the Source Policy.

NOTE: setCovId is a set of policy coverages.

```
   Map<Id, Section_Address_Link__c> mapSectionAddressLink = new Map<Id, Section_Address_Link__c>(
            [select Id,  Policy_Coverage__r.Policy__r.Source_Opportunity__c FROM Section_Address_Link__c WHERE Policy_Coverage__c in :setCovId]
        );

        Map<Id, Section_Address__c> mapSectionAddress = new Map<Id, Section_Address__c>(
            [Select Id,(Select Policy_Coverage__r.Policy__r.Source_Opportunity__c FROM Section_Address_Links__r) From Section_Address__c WHERE ?????]
```

In the first query I say that the Section_Address_Links__c are linked to Policy_Coverage__c. And in my second query, I want to say something similar, i.e. I want to only select those Section_Addresses__c that are linked by Section_Address_Link__c. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new code, I would propose the following solution...

```
Map<Id, Section_Address__c> mapSectionAddress = new Map<Id, Section_Address__c>(
    [Select Id,(Select Policy_Coverage__r.Policy__r.Source_Opportunity__c FROM Section_Address_Links__r) From Section_Address__c WHERE Id IN 
       (SELECT Section_Address__c FROM Section_Address_Link__c WHERE Id = :mapSectionAddressLink.keySet())
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have already updated the code now. I have updated the description with what is not working now.

Comment: I edited the code to help solve your issue. Let me know if that doesn't work. Thanks,